# Automatically select next item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that deletes a note, and it is supposed to automatically select the next note after the first note is deleted. However, it is not working, and i have this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'selected')`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import trashicon from '../../trashicon.png'
import {NoteContext} from '../../noteContext';

const DeleteNote = () => {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useContext(NoteContext);

    const handleDeleteNote =()=> {
        const newNotesList = notes.filter(itemChecked=>itemChecked.selected===false)
        console.log(newNotesList[0])
        for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            if(notes[i].selected === true) {
                newNotesList[i].selected = true;
            }
        
        }
        console.log(newNotesList);
        setNotes(newNotesList);

    }
    return (

            <img src={trashicon} className="delete-icon" onClick={handleDeleteNote}/>

    )
}
export default DeleteNote
```

Comment: Think about what should happen if you have 10 notes, and the first 8 are selected. Take pen and paper, see what the two involved arrays will be, how many times the loop will loop and which indices will be accessed in both arrays. Conclude that this algorithm is not correct and think of a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic is quite incorrect, what if `notes` arr has 5 objects, and `newNotesList` returns 3 different objects, then when you loop it will update first 3 **incorrect** objects in the `newNotesList` array.

IMO, this should be the correct logic.

```
if (!newNotesList.length) return;
for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    //
}

if(notes[i].selected === true) {
    const findElementInNewNotesList = newNotesList.find(el => el.id === notes[i].id);
    if(findElementInNewNotesList.id) newNotesList[i].selected = true;
}
```

This way you're finding the matching object ONLY from `newNotesList`.